# AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'save' - While saving time

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to save `time` when the post was liked. Than I create a field of `like_time` so i can save the time while liking the post BUT When I save the time of like post then it is showing

> AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'save'

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_post_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='like ',blank=True)
    like_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def like_post(request,blogpost_id):
    blogpost = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=blogpost_id)

    if request.GET.get('submit') == 'like_post':
        blogpost.like.add(request.user)
        blogpost.like_time.save()

    else:
        redirect('home')
```

Like is successfuly adding BUT time is not saving and showing error.

I also tried by adding :-

```
from django.utils import timezone

blogpost .like_time.save(timezone.now())
```

BUT It showed me same error.

Than i tried :-

```
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
blogpost.like_time.save(timestamp)
```

It also showed same error.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def like_post(request,blogpost_id):
    blogpost = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=blogpost_id)

    if request.GET.get('submit') == 'like_post':
        blogpost.like.add(request.user)
        blogpost.like_time = timezone.now()
        blogpost.save()

    else:
        redirect('home')
```